# ASP.NET Misconfiguration: Improper Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have below simple class but veracode reporting below flaws

Insufficient Input Validation( 7 flaws) ASP.NET Misconfiguration: Improper Model Validation (CWE ID 1174)(7 flaws)

Please help me to fix this issue

---

Code:

```
namespace Automation.Web.Configuration
    {
        public class AppSettings
        {
            public string BaseURL { get; set; }        
            public string SearchAll { get; set; }
            public string SearchMyReviews { get; set; }
            public string SearchEscalated { get; set; }      
           
          
            public string SearchAllUrl
            {
                get { return BaseURL + SearchAll; }
    
            }
            public string SearchMyReviewsUrl
            {
                get { return BaseURL + SearchMyReviews; }
    
            }
            public string SearchEscalatedUrl
            {
                get { return BaseURL + SearchEscalated; }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply one of Microsoft’s Data Annotation attributes to the property to validate inputs.

For example:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

We could remediate this by using annotations on each of the properties, like so:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z-0-9]{3,16}$")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting StringLength() Data Annotation in every string properties.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are getting this flaw (CWE ID 1174) in controller then**

1. avoid async method.
2. use Bind attribute.
3. use ModelState.IsValid

**if you are getting this flaw (CWE ID 1174) in model then**

1. use Data Annotation attributes like [Required], [MaxLength] etc